# The system cannot find the file specified?

Tags: java, arrays

The following code cannot find the specific file any tips on how I can't fix that. Any help will be appreciated.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class lab8 {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream("haiku.txt");
    Scanner scrn = new Scanner(fileIn);
    System.out.println(scrn.nextLine());
  }
}
```

Comment: where is the file? where is the code? what IDE are you using?

Comment: Well i am using blueJ

Comment: The file is in a folder with the rest of my labs

Comment: Location of the file maybe different. Please check using System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir")); if file is at this location only.

Comment: Still not working

Comment: Is document suppose to be in a pdf??

Comment: @Arsalan go to your BlueJ project and paste haiku.txt in the same location as lab8.java. your project folder is your relative path. when you simply say haiku.txt it assumes it is in the same location as your code.

Comment: @Shawn it is in the same location as the lab8.java folder.

Comment: @Arsalan you need to double check your files. i just ran your code in bluej in my system and it worked. is lab8.java in a package? if it is don't put the text file in the package. leave it at project level.

Comment: @Arsalan check if the path that was print is the same as the actual path of the file. Also if possible show as the directory of your project and where the file is located

Comment: Should it be a pdf file??

Comment: It is in the project level but it is still not working

Answer (score 1):

Try using the absolute path of the file by looking at the file properties.

E.g., /home/demouser/haiku.txt (Linux file)